# Is there a way to change the buttons color ona a jDatePicker

Tags: java

I want to change the buttons color of the jDatePicker and i dont know how.

```
public JDatePickerImpl dateSelector()
{
    UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("text.today", "Today");
    p.put("text.month", "Month");
    p.put("text.year", "Year");
    JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
    datePanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#00387b"));
    datePanel.setForeground(Color.decode("#00387b"));
    JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
    datePicker.setBackground(Color.decode("#00387b"));
    datePicker.setForeground(Color.decode("#00387b"));
    return datePicker;
}
```

It seems like `setBackground()` only adds a small stripe of color next to the button and `setForeground` does absolutely nothing. Syme for the combo box.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the background of the text to. Maybe its easier to use javafx.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this thread is old, but maybe this helps:
You can set Colors of the JDatePicker class by calling

```
ComponentColorDefaults.getInstance().setColor(ComponentColorDefaults.Key.BG_MONTH_SELECTOR, Color.YELLOW);
```

This will set the color for all JDatePicker instances of your project.